# designing a "quite universal" half bridge?

Tags: power, integrated-circuit

A lot of power stuff run on H-bridges controlled by a MCU, would it be possible to design a half bridge and its integrated driver that would work on a very wide range of tension, like 10V to 250V on the power side, 3.3V or 5V on the logic side, probably with integrated dead-time? And creating various ones for various max current (where we can oversize without problem).

I was thinking about only a half bridge so that the user assembles them depending on the situation (biploar motor up to BLDCs to strange steppers). And it would be some kind of lego for power, but with the messy problem of the driver already taken care of. For home fiddling it would be really good, you'd only have the current rating to take care of (and probably thermal dissipation) and you can just over-rate it. Dead-time integration would probably be good to simplify the fiddling too.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess there's a fair selection of cheap and readily available IC's out there that would fill this need for most people.

Comment: If you design it for 250V, it will be much larger and more expensive than one designed for 10V.